# Security on GWT-Platform Applications

Tags: security, gwt, cookies, gwt-platform

I've trying to protect my action against XSRF attacks, following the tutorial in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStartedDispatch#Protecting_against_XSRF_attacks), but, I can't undestand how, where and what I set in `MYCOOKIE`, following the example.

I already make my actions secured (using boilerplate generation), and configure my DispatchServletModule to use `sec_cookie` as the security cookie, but, as I say, I dont know how to set the cookie.

Can someone explain this or show a example?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1: Where I have to put the `@SecurityCookie` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT1: Where I have to put the @SecurityCookie annotation?
>   In your gin client module and guice module.

Also you can read:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/gwt-platform/XSRF

Comment: I just forgot to bind the cookie in the client module too :) thanks, anyway :)